# NetTcpBinding: send and receive simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Consider a service that uses `NetTcpBinding` in duplex mode: the instance of the service receives messages, while the callback is used to send messages in the opposite direction. Can you receive and send data simultaneously? In other words: while the service instance is receiving some data, at the same time can you send data via the callback for the client (the client of the service instance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw TCP can send and receive at the same time. I wouldn't expect the NetTCPBinding to be any different. TCP is a bi-directional connection and the source and destination addresses distinguish between the direction as well as sequence numbers in the TCP packets.

Try it by writing two threads, a sender and a receiver and perform the respective operations in both at the same time.

Comment: Well, in that regard I also found [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx): the [paragraph Callback Reentrancy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx#S4) explains three possible solutions.